# After the Mail is sent the message is showing Error: Your Query is sent successfull

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Need help on issue related to Asp.Net Core MVC in the below screenshot as i sumbit the query the view is returned but the title of the msg "Error" is coming as i want to only render only success message, Thanks...
[Please refer the screenshot attached to have more clearity on issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oSci.png)

Below is my form code

```
<form action="/ContactUs/ContactSubmitQuery" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form" asp-antiforgery="true">
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 sm-6 form-group">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="cname" class="form-control input-css click-cg textbox" id="cname" placeholder="Name"
                               data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
                        <div class="validate"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 sm-6 form-group">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control input-css click-cg textbox" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"
                               data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
                        <div class="validate"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Description</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control click-cg textbox" name="description" rows="5" data-rule="required"
                              data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
                    <div class="validate"></div>
                </div><br>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <div class="loading">Loading</div>
                    <div class="error-message"></div>
                    <div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send</button></div>
            </form>
```

and below is my controller code where am using OK to return success message once the email is sent

```
public IActionResult ContactSubmitQuery()
    {
        string name = Request.Form["cname"];
        string email = Request.Form["email"];
        string message = Request.Form["description"];
        string htmlContent = string.Format("name:{0} <br/> email:{1} <br/> message:{2}", name, email, message);

        SendEmail send = new SendEmail("Test Contact", EmailType.Single);
        send.Send(htmlContent);
        //return Ok("Your Query submitted Successfully");
        return Ok(RedirectToAction("SuccessMessage"));
    }
```

Comment: Please add code and data as text (using code formatting), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; C) are difficult to read clearly by visual impaired user and many more reasons. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: By the way, how we are supposed to guess what your code does just looking at the image of a page?

Comment: Hi Steve Am sorry as am new have added only screenshot

Comment: Hi Steve have shared my code

Comment: Before SendEmail, it works well, could you please tell us what is your SendEmail?